# Convert String to DateTime(yyyy-mm-dd)

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm parsing date from server, date is in this format `6/16/2016 3:15:29 PM` Could you help me please convert date to `2016-06-16`?

I tried:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "MM/dd/yyyy h-m-s t", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

but it's giving me error.

Comment: The time separator in the input string is a colon.

Comment: try this "MM/dd/yyyy h:m:s t"

Comment: Share the error you are getting. I suspect using `-` as your time separator is part of your problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As a tip for future questions: When you write "it's giving me error" you should immediatly think about telling us _which_ error. The error message is one of the most important sources of information about what went wrong. Not telling us the error let's us think that you didn't even read the error message and tried to understand it by yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got 3 problems

- You're not using the correct time separators
- You're using only one `t` when you need two
- You're using two `M` when you only need one

Try

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

The reason you need only one `M` is because `MM` expects a leading zero.  Since the values of the date and time are delimited it's better to use the single versions for month, day, minutes, and seconds because they will work for values with or without leading zeros.

Comment: Since it's `h-m-s` in the question, you, probably, should not change the format for more rigid one (`h:mm:ss`) which *requires* leading zeroes for minutes and seconds

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I've added a comment about that.  The given example doesn't really lead us to know if there are leading zeros for those or not.  But if there are then the singles will not work, so it's up to the OP to determine which is correct.  Also didn't you do the same thing by using a single `d` when the example had two?

Comment: @juharr: +1; changing `dd` -> `d` in my (deleted) answer makes the pattern more *lenient* (it accepts *both* inputs: with and without leading zero). I've changed `dd` into `d` because it must be `M` instead of `MM`, so I've suggested that I should do the same with the day.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You're right, the single is better for `d`, `m`, and `s` because of the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

To execute `DateTime.ParseExact()` format of the input string and the format string must be the same. try this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

**These are interesting in the given input string**(`6/16/2016 3:15:29 PM`):

1. The month is represented in single digit so it should be `M` instead for `MM`. We use `MM` if it is specified as `06`.
2. Same in the case of Hours too. It should be `h` instead for normal `hh`
3. There is a single space in between Date and Time as well as Time and `PM`.
   So we must consider all of these while generating the Format-string for `ParseExact`